# What does "Tingling toes" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I was listening to a song *Top of the world* by *Bridgit Mendler*. She sung some words

> I'm weak in the knees when... You're holding me close.. got tingling toes tonight

What does **tingling toes** mean here?

I know the meaning of both words separately but it is not making sense together for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lyrics are not "tingling toast", but "tingling toes".

As with the "weak in the knees" line, she's describing the physical effects she's feeling from the excitement she experiences when around the song's subject.

Comment: oh! so the lyrics shown were wrong, I cross checked. Sorry for that blunder.